# asp net core with angular

Tags: .net, angularjs, angular-ui-router, asp.net-core

I am having trouble finding a tutorial using asp net core with Angular 1 without using Razor. (I just want to use html) int the web project with a web api solution that will get the requests.

I have been trying to make it work but for some reason i can't get the UI router to work:

like if i do `http://localhost:12112/index.html` it would show the page correcty but when i do `http://localhost:12112/home which is what i want.. it says it can't find it.

My folder structure is:

```
wwwroot
  -app
     -home
        -myhome.controller.js
        -myhome.module.js
        -myhome.router.js
        -myhome.html
  -index.html
```

**myhome.router.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hoa.myhome')
        .config(routeConfig);

    routeConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider']

    function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/app/home/myhome.html'),
            controller: 'myHomeController',
            controllerAs: 'myhctrl'
        })
    };

})();
```

what could i be missing?, or if you could point me to a good tutorial using angular without razor and .net core i would appreciate it.

Comment: You haven't defined a route for home. Your home page is '/'. Are you using IIS? If so you can change your default document to index.html that way you won't have to specify it in the browser.

Comment: but i do not want to show /index.html in the url, i want it to be http://localhost/ , then if i do /home it will bring in the home partial. Yeah it's IIS

Comment: I've created a [tutorial](https://github.com/fabriciokoch/AspnetcoreAngular) using asp.net core and angularjs. There I use a HomeController to serve the index page (it's easier), but you can create a index.html in your wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is plain html and javascript for an SPA that will handle routes by itself like angular, then you can instead of adding a new Project to the solution add a new Empty web site that will be plain html and javascript files.

Things to consider:
1. It will run on a different port/domain so you will have to configure CORS for the web api
2. You will not have any render side functionality available, everythin will be client side
3. Normally visual studio attacth the website to the solution, but place it on differente locations "users/documents/VSVersion/WebSites/" if you dont want that make sure to place it where you want it when you created it

Answer (score 0):

To open the first index.cshtml page, you need to use an action on your Home controller

```
public IActionResult Index(){
    return View();
}
```

This will open the site. Then, in your **index.cshtml**:

```
div ng-app="myApp">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

your `<ui-view></ui-view>` can be populated with your angular html files and the url can be set and changed with your `ui-router`

Comment: I am not using razor (i do not want) i just want plain html - is this possible?. I am just going to make calls to an api that will return my model in json to my angular controller

Comment: If you don't add a HomeController to serve your "/" URL, then, you need to  access localhost/index.html#!/home